# uitableview cells display wrong data when off screen at loading time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that exceeds the screen region. I display some data from an `NSMutableArray` which is filled with `NSDictionary` objects. The objects all have a `group` property which is `true` or `false`, if `group` is true a `UIButton` should be displayed in the cell (to expand the group).
I created a `UIButton` in my cell `prototype` in `storyboard`. I gave it `alpha` 0. If I load the list the button is not in any cell (duh). This is in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if ([[contacts[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"group"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:999];
    [button setAlpha:1.0f];
}
```

If the `group` property is `true` make the button visible. In my current test case the first three objects have `group` set to `true`, the rest have `group` set to `false`. Now my problem is, the first three cells have a visible button (as intended), but some cells further along the table have one as well. I put a breakpoint in the above `if statement`, and it really goes in there only three times.

It happens in a pattern, the first three cells have a button, than five cells don't and than another three have a visible button. Than another five have no button and the last cell does (I think if I add two cells they will also have a button)

The second group of cells that have a button starts just outside the screen, so that may have something to do with it.

One more relevant thing, There is also some text displayed that I take from the same array as the group flag, this text is displayed correct. So it's not that the cells are duplicated somehow, it's just the `if statement` part that screws up.

I double checked the amount of times the program goes into the `if statement` and it's really only three times (the first three entries). If I comment the `setAlpha` call on the button no buttons appear anywhere, so there is also no other place where the button can become visible.

I'm testing on an iPad 4 with iOS 7.1.

If I decrease the height of my rows so all of them fit in the screen, the problem is gone, so It's definitely related to rows falling outside the screen region while loading the data.

---

edit

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(1.0f/255.0f)*220 green:(1.0f/255.0f)*220 blue:(1.0f/255.0f)*225 alpha:1.0f];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"single" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel *screenname = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
        UILabel *username = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
        UIImageView *avatar = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:20];

        if ([[contacts[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"group"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
            NSDictionary *c = contacts[indexPath.section];

            UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:999];
            [button setAlpha:1.0f];

            button.tag = indexPath.section;
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onGroupButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            int numUsersInGroup = [[c valueForKey:@"users"] count];
            NSString *numUsersInGroupString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numUsersInGroup];
            [button setTitle:numUsersInGroupString forState:0];
            [button setNeedsDisplay];

            screenname.text = @"Groep";
            username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[c valueForKey:@"groupName"]];
        } else {
            User *c = (User*)contacts[indexPath.section];

            UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:999];
            [button setAlpha:0.0f];

            screenname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[c valueForKey:@"screenName"]];
            username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[c valueForKey:@"username"]];

            [avatar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"]];
        }

        [GeneralFunctions setFontFamily:@"KozGoPro-ExtraLight" forView:cell andSubViews:YES];
        [GeneralFunctions setFontFamily:@"KozGoPro-Medium" forView:screenname andSubViews:YES];

        [cell.layer setShadowColor:[color CGColor]];
        [cell.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,4)];
        [cell.layer setShadowRadius:3.0f];
        [cell.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
        cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    }

    if (indexPath.row > 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"group" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel *screenname = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
        UILabel *username = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];

        User *c = (User*)[contacts[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"users"][indexPath.row-1];

        screenname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[c valueForKey:@"screenName"]];
        username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[c valueForKey:@"username"]];

        [GeneralFunctions setFontFamily:@"KozGoPro-ExtraLight" forView:cell andSubViews:YES];
        [GeneralFunctions setFontFamily:@"KozGoPro-Medium" forView:screenname andSubViews:YES];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your cell is reused you are not setting the button back to the `0.0` alpha. You need to reset your cell or change your cell's property whenever you reuse a cell otherwise it'll show the old content

```
if ([[contacts[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"group"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
    NSDictionary *c = contacts[indexPath.section];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:999];
    [button setAlpha:1.0f];

    //this line changes your tag and hence in else condition for reused cell it'll come nil
    button.tag = indexPath.section;

} else {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:999];
    [button setAlpha:0.0f];
}
```

---

Suggestion instead of accessing button by tag access it by using property by type casting the cell into your custom cell

Comment: This does not fix the issue, sadly. How do I 'reset my cell'?

Comment: [cellForRowAtIndexPath code](http://pastebin.com/j7MU0QbR). It's pretty messy, sorry.

Comment: uncomment this code `button.tag = indexPath.section;`. Here you are changing the button's tag and when you try to get the view by tag 999 you'll get nil.

Comment: I need to set the button's tag though (I do that after 'getting' the button) to be able to know which button was pressed in my button callback. I'll try commenting it now.

Comment: Ok, commenting that line worked, thanks :). Now I just have to find another way to detect which button was pressed.....

Comment: just access that button by your property if not the create it. I've also updated my answer